# How much memory size for a local variable is worth it to using malloc()?

Tags: c, operating-system

If I have a struct as local variable which is only used in a function inside but the size of it is a little bit big but smaller than the stack frame max size, I want to define it directly to avoid the spending
 of calling malloc() but also I'm afraid of the sum of size of variables exceed the limit of stack frame size.  Is there any standard for the size of local variable to using malloc?

Comment: What size is the structure?  Unless it weighs in at more than a kilobyte, it isn't worth worrying about unless you are working in a space-constrained environment.  If the structure is more than a kilobyte, why is it so big — are you sure it is designed right?  I'm using 1 KB as a convenient round number — the threshold is bigger than 128 bytes, and less than megabytes. You get about 1 MiB stack space on Windows, and 8 MiB on most Unix systems (by default). If you're sailing close to the edge (a multiple kilobyte structure), how do you create a sensibly sized single function using it?  Design?

Comment: This is just a metaphor and it could be a array like buf[1024], not only structure.I'm learning theory of operating system by reading a open source os for educational purposes, there is a lot of mallocing a buf area which only is used in the inside of function and the size of it is neither too big nor too little like uint8_t* buf = sys_malloc(512). This reminds me of this question. @Jonathan Leffler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a few things you could do:

- Check your compiler documentation for an option to change the size of the stack. This is different from compiler to compiler. If you are on linux, then you may need to change the environment variable that tells the size of the stack instead.
- Make a static variable. This will place it in the data segment of your program memory. This will also make any changes to the variable stay from one call of your function to the other as the static variables have a lifetime that is the entire run of the program and are only initialized once.

Comment: Are you sure there's an environment variable for the stack size limit?  It is a property of the process (inherited by its children), and is found using `ulimit` at the shell and [`getrlimit()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getrlimit.html) or `setrlimit()` in a program.

Answer (score 1):

This does of course depend on the OS, but a subjective rule of thumb is that objects somewhere around 1 kib are better off on the heap (or in `.data`) than on the stack.

Though some libraries where they expect that one out of many objects might be big, put everything on the heap just for the sake of consistency.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to allocate a small but not-known-at-compile-time amount of memory on the stack, use alloca()

Comment: Or better, use VLA.

Comment: Using `alloca()` allocates the memory from the stack.  If you're worried about running out of space on the stack, using `alloca()` exacerbates rather than alleviates the problem — and you can't recover from `alloca()` failures.  Similar comments apply to a VLA on the stack.